# Writing a function that accepts NSString and floats

Tags: objective-c, function, nsstring, floating-point

I'm trying to do an iPad application.

In one of the functions, I'm supposed to return a value depending on the string input.

Here's the code:

```
float myFunction(float t, NSString * Color){

    if ([Color isEqual:@"blue"])
       return t*100;

    else if ([Color isEqual:@"red"])
       return t*2;

    else
       return t;
}
```

But somewhere my program does something wrong.  Since I don't get the number I'm expecting. Is it possible that this code is the missing link?

I get no errors or warnings.

Comment: What is it that you're expecting, and what do you get? Please give an example, since the code looks alright.

Comment: Im was not sure of how to use quotes " " and at @ when handeling NSStrings. And since the compier seems to like both without @"red" and just 'red' (without ' ')  I felt the need of askiong.

Comment: ... something in my code (2500lines of code) is not dooing as expected, I was hopping this was the problem....
But happily Not =)

Answer (score 1):

instead of `isEqual` you should use `isEqualToString`

and change `Color` to `color`

Try if this makes a difference (if not the problem lies elswhere in the code):

```
float myFunction(float t, NSString * color){

    if ([color isEqualToString:@"blue"])
       return t*100.0;

    else if ([color isEqualToString:@"red"])
       return t*2.0;

    else
       return t;
}
```

If you want your function to look more like obj-c method then use:

```
-(CGFloat) myFunctionForT:(CGFloat)t andColor:(NSString *)color {

        if ([color isEqualToString:@"blue"])
           return t*100.0;

        else if ([color isEqualToString:@"red"])
           return t*2.0;

        else
           return t;
}
```

The main reason for using `color` instead of `Color` and `100.0` instead of `100` is that a bit more discipline in coding saves you hours and hours of debugging time.

Comment: what is the different in using "C" or "c" ?
 what kind of different things will happen if I use e.g
 isEqual:@"blue" instead of  isEqualToString:@"blue"
or
 isEqual:blue instead of  isEqualToString:blue

Comment: betwenn C and c its just a matter of discipline :) Capital first letters shoud really be used for names of classes, protocols... and small for objects, methods... as For isEqual and isEqualToString: not sure how compiler treats them but in obj-c isEqualToString should be used for strings. as for blue and @"blue": first one would be comparing to a variable called blue, second one to a string constant

Comment: THANKS! this means a LOT to me! = )
So,
    if ([color isEqualToString:@"blue"])
  

I'm checking if the color is named as the color, 'blue'

 And   if ([color isEqualToString:blue])
    

I'm checking is the color is the same as the vaiable named 'blue'

Comment: Hmm how does this effect my function call??
myFunction(20, blue) or myFunction(20,@"blue").
The compiler seams to like them both

Comment: @user1228595: for first post: yes, you got it. for second post: do you have a constant or variable like NSString *blue = @"blue"; if not, your compiler warning settings are set much to loose :)

Comment: NSString *blue = @"blue" Nope I do not..
Should I not have NSString *blue = @"red" as well? one for each color makes more sense: I understand is as a predefinition of feasible colors.

My previous programming skills is little java and a lot matlab-function-coding, so I gladly read post like the above code example, its a matter of fact that im writing an iPad-app, so why not lear objC! Thanks!

Comment: No need for NSString *blue = @"blue"; and NSString *red = @"red"; This was just theoretical - you'll be fine simply using @"blue" and @"red" string constants in this case. By the way: how do you call this myFunction? I'm a bit suspicious about your 'color' parameter. Is it really NSString or is it UIColor?

Comment: actually is not a color in my own code, this is just an example, is a grad such as "A1",...,"A5", "B1",..."B5" and so on

Comment: one example of how I call one of my many functions is
 float X = myFunction(20, @"grade")   Should I be embarrassed?

Comment: Gonna try as example above as soon as a can find time, it gonna take a couple of hours to rewrite it =( . Possible that I try it out on a small part of my program, still gonna take some time. I'll keep you posted

Comment: btw I have four (4) float variables how do I tweak -(CGFloat) myFunctionForT:(CGFloat)t andColor:(NSString *)color { in to this?

Comment: The cleanest way would be creating a class containing 4 float properties.

Comment: Im back, and my findings is:
The mayor error was somewhere else in the code
BUT since I now understand above better it helped me find the error.
Note that I did not rewrite the code in to more obj-c-ish code, worked anyway =)